# Error 1004 when assigning Range.Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a formula in VBA into an Excel sheet. This is my code:

```
destWorkBook.Sheets("Forecast Sheet").range("A" & i).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C" & i & ", ""'Forecast Sheet Old'""!C:C,0)), ""'NEW'"", IF(H" & i & "=""'Forecast Sheet Old'""!H" & i & ",""''"",""'CHANGED'""))"
```

Somehow it doesn't work whatever I try:

```
destWorkBook.Sheets("Forecast Sheet").range("A" & i).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C" & i & ", 'Forecast Sheet Old'!C:C,0)), 'NEW', IF(H" & i & "='Forecast Sheet Old'!H" & i & ",'','CHANGED'))"
```

Like this or a million other things, it's simply not taking the formula.

The error message is:

> Run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: this means nothing as you need to provide more detail: Somehow it doesnt work whatever i try.  What doesn't work, what is happening?

Comment: Sorry pretty late over here, edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work, to many apostrophes

```
destWorkBook.Sheets("Forecast Sheet").Range("A" & i).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C" & i & ", 'Forecast Sheet Old'!C:C,0)), ""NEW"", IF(H" & i & "='Forecast Sheet Old'!H" & i & ","""",""CHANGED""))"
```

Comment: Beat me to it. OP seems under the impression that they can happily substitute double-quotes with single-quotes anywhere in the formula - that will do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Again it was pretty late yesterday and i tried so many different things but just couldnt solve it.